# How to custimize the height of Table Cell with respect to height of image in it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i have a UITableView and i am showing different images in cells,each image has different height,how can i customize the cell height with respect to heights of images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method `– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a).

For example, if you're using Interface Builder, right-button-drag from your table view to the controller itself, add `<UITableViewDelegate>` after `UIViewController` in your view controller's class declaration, and add something like this to the the class `.m` file:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UIImage *image = imagesArray[indexPath.row];
  return image.size.height + 5; // 5 = margin.
}
```

Comment: I assume you have an array of images, called `imagesArray`. You probably have your images stored somewhere?